# Compiling boost with b2 for a custom architecture

Tags: boost, bjam

Boost version 1.68.0

Build requres flag for g++ `-mcpu=r2000`

```
 b2 -cxxflags="-std=c++11 -mcpu=r2000" -j 12
```

During build b2 calls g++-compiler with `-mcpu=v7` which this build doesn't support.

Comment: What is the target architecture? In my quick scans `v7` implies sparc, where r2000 seems related to MIPS. Did you specify the architecture as well?

Comment: @sehe there were no other options given. target's name is R2000 cpu which is technically V9 instruction set. But b2 substitutes v7 instead of R2000 or v9. Neither compiler nor OS don't support such.

Comment: My point is "V9 of what" - I think it might help to inform Boost of what architecture you are targetting. You even avoided mentioning it in your reply, while I specifically pointed out the two conflicting candidates to disambiguate.

Comment: @sehe there are no conflicting candidates. Compiler supports only untrasparc types, both r2000 and v9 are ultrasparc, -mcpu=native equals for it to r2000, it's the machine compilation happens. How I supposed to tell b2 to use option I give? directly

Comment: I never suggested that there *was* a conflict. I literally only said *I* was finding conflicting information trying to *guess* the architecture you were targetting. Thanks for letting us know what the target architecture is supposed to be. You might want to add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Boost's GCC toolchain definitions do not know about r2000 at all.

This might explain it defaulting to the default value. I haven't tried, but there might be a diagnostic message related to this. If not, you could file an issue asking for one to be added to save people time wasted debugging this condition.

Here's the relevant list from tools/build/src/tools/gcc.jam (in 1.82.0):

```
# Sparc
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : v7 : -mcpu=v7 : default ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : cypress : -mcpu=cypress ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : v8 : -mcpu=v8 ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : supersparc : -mcpu=supersparc ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : sparclite : -mcpu=sparclite ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : hypersparc : -mcpu=hypersparc ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : sparclite86x : -mcpu=sparclite86x ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : f930 : -mcpu=f930 ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : f934 : -mcpu=f934 ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : sparclet : -mcpu=sparclet ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : tsc701 : -mcpu=tsc701 ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : v9 : -mcpu=v9 ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : ultrasparc : -mcpu=ultrasparc ;
cpu-flags gcc OPTIONS : sparc : ultrasparc3 : -mcpu=ultrasparc3 ;
```

Also keep in mind that there might be known issues, seeing you're using an older version of boost.

According [to this post](https://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2015/08/28188.php) specific versions might require a work-around like specifying e.g. `instruction-set=v9` on the command line.